# Where can you register for the Crysis 3 Open Beta?

Tags: crysis-3

I heard about a open beta for Crysis 3, starting this month.
Where can you register for this?

Comment: It is unlikely that this is real. If anything it is likely to be a demo not a beta. As the game is scheduled for release mid Feb. <1 month for a beta seems unrealistic.

Comment: @ColinD: read the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Crysis 3 Beta will be live from January 29th through February 12th for PC, Xbox 360, and PS3 and in English only.  The Open Beta will give players a chance to play Crysis 3 Multiplayer pre-release.  There is no pre-registration required.

According to [EA's FAQ](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RlsbLgGmFBAJ:https://help.ea.com/article/crysis-3-open-beta-faq%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) (Google Cached page, actual page 404's):

**For PC users**, just open up and log in to Origin. It will be in the My Games tab.    Download and install the same way you would do any other game in Origin.  Make sure that you have the minimum system requirements:

- Windows Vista, 7 or 8
- DirectX 11 graphics card with 1GB Video RAM
- Dual core CPU
- 2GB Memory (3GB on Vista)

**For Xbox 360 users**, open the Xbox Demo section of the store.  Download and install the same way you would any other demo.  You will need to have an Xbox Live Gold account to participate.

**For PS3 users**, open the PSN store and it will be in the demos section.  Download and install the same way you would do any other demo.

Comment: There isn't a registration. Added that in the answer.

Comment: @kalina that's sort of the point of an open beta.